# Angularjs - get value from external DOM element

Tags: angularjs

I am writing an angular application as module inside an existing application.
There is a hidden field in the outer application that I need.

My question is what is the best way to fetch this value and use it in my angular application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add your attribute in `window` object from anywhere in your code, use

```
<script>
window.my_value = 'value';
</script>
```

And in your controller, please inject `$window` service and then use

```
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $window) {
console.log($window.my_value);
})
```

OR

You can directly use this hidden field's value, like

```
var obj = angular.element(document.querySelector("#hiddenFieldId"));
console.log(obj.val());
```

If you have an ID/Class for that input..

Comment: thanks guys for the help, the second option is will probably to the trick for me, the thing is I don't wanna use it in the controller. i wonder if I can use something like that in a factory....

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the value with pure JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('id');
```